# How to use mathutils.noise.hetero_terrain?

Tags: python

I am not sure what I am missing, but all I get is a value of 1 on every return..

```
value_texture = numpy.zeros((100 * 100), dtype=numpy.float32)
for y in range(100):
    for x in range(100):
        loc = y * 100 + x
        value_texture[loc] = mathutils.noise.hetero_terrain((x, y, 0), 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`mathutils.noise.hetero_terrain(...)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.noise.html#mathutils.noise.hetero_terrain)**

> Returns the heterogeneous terrain value from the noise basis at the
>   specified position.

[image]

Out of interest made a little script to apply each of the noise types as a shapekey on z height of a 100x100 mesh grid. Script below, result above.

```
import bpy
from mathutils.noise import hetero_terrain as ht
context = bpy.context

H = 0.4
lacunarity = 1
octaves = 1
offset = 0.3
noise_basii =  (
    'BLENDER', 
    'PERLIN_ORIGINAL', 
    'PERLIN_NEW', 
    'VORONOI_F1', 
    'VORONOI_F2', 
    'VORONOI_F3', 
    'VORONOI_F4', 
    'VORONOI_F2F1', 
    'VORONOI_CRACKLE', 
    'CELLNOISE')

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_grid_add(
        size=10,
        x_subdivisions=100,
        y_subdivisions=100
        )
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
sk = ob.shape_key_add(name="Basis")
for nb in noise_basii:
    sk = ob.shape_key_add(name=nb)

    for v in me.vertices:
        sk.data[v.index].co.z = ht(v.co,
                H,
                lacunarity,
                octaves,
                offset,
                noise_basis=nb
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
value_texture[loc] = mathutils.noise.hetero_terrain((x*.01, y*.01, 0), 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1)
```