# How do you generate Blender's built-in random textures using the Python API?

Tags: python, texturing

The Python API docs list (referencing 2.83, since that's the version of Blender I'm currently using most) a number of specific random generators:

https://docs.blender.org/api/2.83/mathutils.noise.html?highlight=noise#module-mathutils.noise

A few of these -- e.g., Voronoi -- overlap with the `Type` options for textures, but mostly there appears to be little correspondence (the docs indicate `hetero_terrain`, `multi_fractal`, etc functions that do not correspond to a texture type, while the texture types indicate `Magic`, `Clouds`, and so forth that do not seem to correspond to any of the random generators). [The `noise_basis` types, on the other hand, obviously correspond to the list given in the docs, 1-for-1, not withstanding `BLENDER` in the docs versus `BLENDER ORIGINAL` in the Blender drop-down menu.]

How are Blender's specific built-in random texture types each generated? Is it from composing/transforming these built-in random generators, and, if so, how?

Comment: Some of the underlying noise algorithms are probably similar if not identical, but mathutils has a different role and if I had to guess it's not directly used to generate colors for procedural textures. You can look into the source C++ code of Blender and find out how it is generated though.

Comment: Somewhat related re `noise.hetero_terrain` usage. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126299/how-to-use-mathutils-noise-hetero-terrain   IIRC there is another question / answer detailing the hard-coding in source of noise values  (maybe to do with fcurve modifier) So the default is always the same.